# How do I integrate Pyhon in HTML?

Tags: python, html, integration

So, I guess this is a very basic question, but for some reason, I can't find any videos or text tutorials on how to use `Python` output data inside my `HTML` code, save for using `Django` or `Flask`. I'm using `PyCharm` and have a `Python` file called `Main.py` and a `HTML` file called `myHTML.html`.

For simplicity's sake, lets just say I want the data of the variable `test = 3` from the `Main.py` to be displayed on my webpage `myHTML.html`. How would  I go about doing this in the `HTML` structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lime</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lime</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're gonna need to add an endpoint exposing `test` using a web framework(such as Django as Flask), and add code consuming that endpoint in the HTML file(usually with Javascript).

Comment: @Mikael Brenner Ah, ok, so there's no quick and easy way to do it. Guess that's why I didn't find anything save for Flask and Django. Thanks!

Comment: not sure how this is possible to miss, since this is exactly what there are tutorials for when looking at any web-framework. try bottle or flask documentation as a starting point. bottle is great for getting the hang of the basics concepts. probably worthwhile to somewhere along the lines look for the term template

Answer (score 2):

Python is not PHP - if you want to serve dynamic HTTP content using Python, you need to use either the totally outdated cgi protocol (hint: don't even try), or setup a wsgi gateway (hint: that's the way to go) - and then you'll be better off using an existing wsgi framework like Flask or Django, which both use a template system.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate python within HTML you could use Jinja2 and Pdfkit (python packages) to integrate variables from a python context into any html File.

I remember once I passed a whole DataFrame. :-)